Prevent deleted user from navigating the website?
When I delete a user, they are still able to navigate the site.
Is it possible to clear their session data so that they get redirected to the Login page instead?
Part of the problem is that the user deleting the account is likely a different user. So clearing cookies won't affect the deleted user.

My cookies contain the (encrypted) username. Now it's easy to check if that user actually exists.

@PoulBak: But how does that address the question?

Well, do you just accept a token without verifying - and serving everything based on that token? Then you have a bad login system.

@PoulBak: I'm using ASP.NET Core Identity. I didn't really want to write everything from scratch. I'm trying to work with that infrastructure.

What does your current authentication process look like? It's hard to tell what in ASP.NET Core Identity you're doing/not doing.

@Jimenemex: It's just "out of the box" ASP.NET Core Identity. And I'm deleting the user using UserManager<TUser>.DeleteAsync(TUser). This is completely standard. I would think anyone who has used ASP.NET Core Identity would be familiar with how you use it.

If you are going to hit the database for a runtime test on every request, you might as well implement ITicketStore to shrink cookies at the same time.

You can always check for the currently authenticated user on every action executing to ensure the user actually exists within UserManager. You'd still want to invalidate the cookies/session, depending on how tolerant you are with them being active. I would set their expiration to some small interval to start with to prevent them being re-used.
public override async Task OnActionExecutingAsync(ActionExecutingContext context) 
{
    var user = context.HttpContext.User;
 
    // Get the userId by the name or some other method     
    var userId = user.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

    var dbUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

    if (dbUser == null)
    {
        context.Result = RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
    }

    await base.OnActionExecutingAsync(context);
}


That should do it. However, it isn't very efficient as it requires an additional round trip to the database on every single request. Also, I don't believe Razor Pages has an OnActionExecuting() function.
